# A word or term for someone who likes to insult other people?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests, social-interaction

I'm wondering if there's a word or term for a person who looks for an opportunity to insult and berate other people.

I'm sure you've all been there; you're using an online public forum, like Facebook, to voice an opinion. There's always that one person who gets completely offended, or they take things completely out of context. They then proceed to publicly scold and shame you - excessively, it seems. It makes you wonder if maybe they're just looking for something to complain about, or if they enjoy being abusive? Maybe they just get a kick out of making you look bad, and want everyone else to dislike you?

"Troll" and "butthurt" seem to fit fairly well, but I was hoping to find a more traditional English equivalent.

Comment: Verbal aggressor or belligerent.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a [***bully***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bully) to me.

> A person who uses strength or influence to harm or intimidate those who are weaker:
>   *he is a ranting, domineering bully*

Answer (score 0):

**A stirrer** if you don't mind being slightly offensive **shit stirrer**

​

> **Stirrer**  noun 2. informal a person who deliberately causes trouble
>   [...]
>
> If you refer to someone as a stirrer, you disapprove of them because they often try to cause trouble. [British, informal,disapproval]
>   - [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stirred)

> **shit stirrer** someone who makes trouble for other people, especially by making known facts that they would prefer to keep secret:
>
> *He didn't need to tell her that - he's just a shit stirrer.*
>   - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shit-stirrer

Answer (score 0):

***[faultfinder](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faultfinder)*** (M-W):

> a person who criticizes someone or something often in a way that is
> not fair or reasonable
>
> **Examples** of faultfinder in a sentence:
>
> Faultfinders were quick to point out inconsistencies in the study.
>
> no sooner had we finished decorating the church than the parish
> faultfinder decided that she didn't like it
>
> **Synonyms**:
>
> carper, castigator, caviler (or
> caviller), censurer, criticizer, disparager, critic, hypercritic,
> knocker, niggler, nitpicker

***[detractor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/detractor)*** (M-W):

> Definition of detract *transitive verb*
>
> 1 archaic :  to speak ill of
>
> 2 archaic :  to take away
>
> intransitive verb :  to diminish the importance, value, or
> effectiveness of something —often used with from
>
> small errors that do not seriously detract from the book
>
> -**detractor**

Also related (from M-W): [disparager](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disparager), [denigrator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denigrator), [belittler](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belittler), [chastiser](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chastiser), [reproacher](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reproacher), [rebuker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebuker)

Answer (score 0):

[Confrontational](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confrontational):

> Tending to deal with situations in an aggressive way; hostile or argumentative

or

[Antagonistic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/antagonistic):

> Showing or feeling active opposition or hostility towards someone or something

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Your answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length. I've edited your answer and try to follow this format next time. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Jerk** makes it through most of the web's auto-content filters.
It covers your specific need, and a lot of others as well.

Answer (score 0):

A **douche**.

From Merriam-Webster's (gosh, I've been waiting for decades for this word to make it into first-rate dictionaries as a derogatory):

*4 chiefly US slang :an obnoxious or offensive person :douchebag In the show Edward is portrayed as a thin-skinned, self-serving faker, or, as one of the show's principals Stan so pithily repeats throughout the program, "a liar," "a fake," and "a douche." — David Daegling et al.*